# Выбрать системную мелодию для приложения

Tags: java, android

Я хочу сделать выбор системной мелодии для своего приложения. Поиск меня привел к использованию константы `ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS` для выбора мелодии из окна системных настроек таким подходом:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS), 1);
```

Однако вместо ожидаемого меню для выбора системной мелодии открывается окно настроек "Звук и вибрация".[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Оттуда можно перейти к выбору мелодии, но на мой взгляд это выглядит плохо, поскольку пользователь может запутаться, куда заходить.

Мой поиск по интернету ничего не нашел, хотя я потратил достаточно времени. Есть похожие вопросы [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461874/android-how-to-open-notification-sound-settings-menu-in) и [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656456/how-to-start-an-activity-which-display-sound-display-screen) многолетней давности, но там я не нашел ответа. Создалось впечатление, что многие разработчики смирились с таким положением дел и остановились на варианте, предложенном выше. Однако у меня на телефоне стоит приложение с гугл плэй, которое как-то это делает (из настроек я могу попасть сразу в окно выбора мелодии минуя окно "звук и вибрация". Значит такой способ есть.

UPDATE:

Еще нашел [подобный](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623225/go-to-settings-screen) вопрос. Судя по последнему комментарию, способ, которым я пытаюсь это сделать, стал legacy, начиная с Nouget-версии. Пока вопрос остается открытым. Так же там есть ответ с использованием `RingtonePreference` (я проверил на `PreferenceFragment` и это то что надо), но он мне не подходит, поскольку я использую `AppCompatActivity`, которая требует использовать `PreferenceFragmentCompat` вместо `PreferenceFragment` - но для него нет реализации `RingtonePreference`(

Comment: Еще было б неплохо, если бы тот, кто минусует, хоть как-нибудь прокомментировал свой минус. А то ни ответа, ни совета

Answer (score 0):

```
public void pickRingtone() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Выбор мелодии");
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
                if (uri != null) {
                    //uri выбранной мелодии
                }
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за быстрый ответ. Но это не совсем то. Я пробовал подобный вариант. И сейчас еще раз попробовал ваш, чтобы вспомнить: он мне не дает выбрать системные звуки. То есть он предлагает выбор приложения для навигации по муз. файлам и выбрать мелодию из них. Но среди них нет системных звуков